# Google Cloud Security Risk API

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

We have received mail from Google mentioned that "It appears that your project is performing intrusion attempts against a third-party. We will suspend your project in 3 days unless you correct the problem by ensuring your project traffic directed at third-parties is expected, and that your project has not been compromised."

I have cross checked all my access/error log, Firewall ports,DDoS log, etc. I've not found any problem from server end. Has anyone faced same issue?. It's critical for my client project.pls help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack is not google support.

Comment: In the short term find out from Google which IP addresses the 3rd party is at and block outbound traffic to those addresses from your instances using iptables or equivalent. Then try to find out which processes are attempting to send to those addresses. Or just delete all instances and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: There was SSH brute force attack from my google cloud instances as mentioned by google team. "Based on our records, we detected SSH brute forcing attacks originating from IP x.x.x.x targeting more than 113 IP addresses on 2016/06/21." . I've not found any log for ssh outbound traffic. but i got logs for SSH brute force attack in my instances which is already banned my fail2ban service. where can i find out ssh outbound traffic  logs ? i m using centos 7.

Comment: As i mentioned to google we are having only static page websites and in audit logs we've not found such brute force attack issue. Btw google has removed warning flag in my project.:)